# Reading data in anchor JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am working on a piece of code where I want to fetch the td string and anchor text from the same tr:

```
<tr>
  <td class='labelOptional_1'>TD1 text here</td>
  <td width='15%' class='label2'><div align='center'>&nbsp;</div></td>
  <td width='15%' class='label2'><div align='center'>&nbsp;</div></td>
  <td width='15%' class='label2'>
    <div align='center'> <a href='Relative_URL_1'>hrefURL 1 in anchor tag ||</a> </div>
  </td>
<tr>
   <td class='labelOptional_1'>TD2 text here</td>
   <td width='15%' class='label2'><div align='center'>&nbsp;</div></td>
   <td width='15%' class='label2'><div align='center'>&nbsp;</div></td>
   <td width='15%' class='label2'>
      <div align='center'> <a href='Relative_URL_2'>hrefURL 2 in anchor tag ||</a> </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class='labelOptional_1'>TD3 here</td>
   <td width='15%' class='label2'><div align='center'>&nbsp;</div></td>
   <td width='15%' class='label2'><div align='center'>&nbsp;</div></td>
   <td width='15%' class='label2'>
      <div align='center'> <a href='Relative_URL_3'>hrefURL 3 in anchor tag ||</a> </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I want the output as:

```
TD1 text here Relative_URL_1
TD2 text here Relative_URL_2
```

Current output:

```
TD1 text here Relative_URL_1
TD2 text here Relative_URL_2
TD3 text here Relative_URL_3
```

Below is the code:

```
org.jsoup.select.Elements trs = doc.select("tr:contains(text)");        //fetch table rows
        for(Element tr :trs)
        {
            org.jsoup.select.Elements tds = tr.select("td:containsOwn(text)");
            for (Element td:tds){
                        sb.append(td.text());
                        sb.append(',');
            }
            org.jsoup.select.Elements anchor = tr.select("a");
            for(Element aHref : anchor){
                sb.append(aHref.attr("abs:href"));
                sb.append(',');
             }
           sb.append('\n');
         }
```

The code reads the required TD, however, reads all the Anchor tags outside 
the tr,td which mathces the contains condition (having "text" word) in TD.
I want the code to read only those anchor tags which belong to that specific 
`<tr>`

Comment: So you need to get only first two list from the `tr`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 2nd loop, Modify your code as following

```
      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.htmlParser());
    org.jsoup.select.Elements trs = doc.select("tr:contains(text)");        //fetch table rows

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Element tr : trs) {
        org.jsoup.select.Elements tds = tr.select("td:containsOwn(text)");

        for (Element td : tds) {
            String anchor = tr.select("a").attr("href");
            sb.append(td.text() +" "+anchor);
        }
        sb.append('\n');
    }
```

Comment: utsav anand : Hi, Thanks for your reply..! The issue is containsOwn points to <td> at 0th location, and Anchor tag is present in <td> at 3rd location in the same tr.